Infinite Loop Issue in Assembly
I am working on a simple assembly program that uses a loop to print a message a specific number of times. However, the loop is not terminating as expected and runs indefinitely.
I am new to assembly language, so please keep that in mind
Here is a snippet of my code:
.section .data
zprava: .asciz "opakuji smycku\n"

.section .text
.global _start
.intel_syntax noprefix

_start:
mov rcx, 5
smycka:
cmp rcx, 0
jg konec
mov rax, 1
mov rdi, 1
lea rsi, [zprava]
mov rdx, 17
syscall
dec rcx
jmp smycka

konec:
mov rax, 60
xor rdi, rdi
syscall


syscall destroys rcx. Save and restore it or use a different register.

Thank you it worked I use push and pop instruction, thanks very much
